# Trigged a function with 2 parameters after delay

Tags: ios, selector, grand-central-dispatch, nstimer

Can someone help me for this problem : I need to trigged a function with 2 parameters after a determined time (2 or 3 seconds).
I've tried to do it with a dispatch_after block, but it can lead me to a message send to deallocated instance. 
I've also tried with `NSInvocation` and a scheduled timer, but my parameters are booleans, so I can't use `setArgument:atIndex:`

Any tip for this?

**EDIT** *add sample code*

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC ), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [myPullableView setOpened:NO animated:YES];
});
```

When the view controller is deallocated, its properties (and so `myPullableView`) are deallocated too.

BTW, I'm using ARC.

Comment: Can you share a code example of something you've tried? `dispatch_after` will probably be the easiest way to achieve what you're after, so perhaps that example?

Comment: you can save bool as NSNumber. [NSNUmber numberWithBool:bool];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the block approach you currently have, just make the reference weak so that it is safe to reference:

```
__weak typeOf(myPullableView) *weakPullableView = myPullableView;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC ), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakPullableView setOpened:NO animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`[self performSelector:@selector(delayDo:) withObject:@[@NO, @YES] afterDelay:2.0] ;`

```
- (void)delayDo:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSNumber * num1 = array[0] ;
    NSNumber * num2 = array[1] ;
    BOOL open = [num1 boolValue] ;
    BOOL animated = [num2 boolValue] ;
    [myPullableView setOpened:NO animated:YES] ;
}
```

cancel the delay operation when dealloc.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self] ;
}
```